# How to return moved value as `Err` in loop using question mark operator?

Tags: rust

In the code below, `version 1` does not compile, whereas `version 2` does.

```rust
fn foo(text: String) -> Result<u32, String> {
    let mut acc: u32 = 0;
    for string in text.split("_") {
        let result: Option<u32> = string.parse::<u32>().ok();

        // version 1
        let x: u32 = result.ok_or(text)?;
        acc += x;

        // version 2
        // if let Some(x) = result {
        //     acc += x;
        // } else {
        //     return Err(text)
        // }
    }
    Ok(acc)
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `text`
   --> src/main.rs:102:35
    |
96  | fn foo(text: String) -> Result<u32, String> {
    |        ---- move occurs because `text` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
102 |         let x: u32 = result.ok_or(text)?;
    |                                   ^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

The issue is that I'm moving `text` into another function (`ok_or`) on each loop iteration.
So I understand the error message, but is there still a way out to use the shorthand `?` notation in this case? The `version 2` is the shortest I could get but it still seems too verbose.

(this is just a MWE / toy example, my question is not about summing numbers in a string)

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot afford a copy on the `Err` case, and you have a lot of places like that, you can use a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! try_opt {
    ( $v:expr, $e:expr $(,)? ) => {
        match $v {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => return Err($e),
        }
    }
}

let x: u32 = try_opt!(result, text);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford a string clone in the `Err` case (not the happy path), you can just take a reference, as `String` implements `From<&String>`:

```rust
let x: u32 = result.ok_or(&text)?;
```